# Proving eigenvectors of matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For the following question, I am interested in part (b):
[image]

I'm not quite sure how to show what the question is asking. I know that $ABv = λv$ for some non-zero vector $v$. My attempt at this question has been multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$ to get

$$A^{-1}ABv = A^{-1}λv,$$ then $Bv = A^{-1}λv$ , now I have isolated $Bv$ but unsure if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know whether $A$ is an invertible matrix, so we can't multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.
Instead, note that $AB \mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}$ implies, by the associative law,
$$(BA)(B\mathbf{v})=B(AB \mathbf{v})=B( \lambda\mathbf{v}).$$
Can you take it from here? Why is $B\mathbf{v}$ a non-zero vector?

Comment: as for continuing the proof, I'm not sure I could, unless what you have provided is the entirety of the proof. As for why $Bv$ is a non-zero vector, my understanding is, we know $v$ is non-zero, the eigenvalue $λ$ is non-zero and then I'm guessing $B$ is not a $0$ matrix therefore $Bv$ is non-zero?

Comment: Well, one easy final step is missing. No, we can have a non zero matrix $B$ and a non zero vextor $v$ such that $Bv=0$. Actually we now that $AB \mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}\not= 0$, so...

Comment: is the final step $λ(Bv) = AB(Bv)$? 

so we know $λ=AB$ which is non-zero therefore $A and B$ are non-zero matrices? its probably very obvious but I can't figure it out

Comment: Yes, this is the final step. Now if $Bv=0$ then $ABv=?$... What may we conclude?

Comment: $ABv = A0 = 0$ ? This cannot be true since the question says $ABv = λv$ ??

Comment: Yes, now you got it!!

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help and developing my understanding!!